# Need a Regex in JavaScript to match '/' or '/login'

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need a regex to match either '/' or '/login' at the end of my url. Here is my regex which I am trying.

`/\/(login)?$/.test(window.location.href)`

This is what the expected result.

```
/\/(login)?$/.test('/')             //true
/\/(login)?$/.test('/login')        //true
/\/(login)?$/.test('//')            // false
/\/(login)?$/.test('/login/login')  //false
```

Basically I want to match exactly one set not multiple.

Comment: Anything wrong with simply listing the two alternatives ...? `(\/|\/login)$`

Comment: So you want to match a string that is not preceded by another string?

Comment: I tried that. I evaluates true for other 2 cases. `/(\/|\/login)$/.test('/login/login/')` and `/(\/|\/login)$/.test('//')`.

Comment: Yes I want exactly one match. No repeat at the end of my current url.

Comment: Wouldn't `/` and `/login` be the same thing? A single `/tvtctrctx` would be as true as a single `/login`

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you're testing `window.location.href` when what you really want is `window.location.pathname`. You'd then just need anchors at both ends of the RegExp:

```
/^\/(login)?$/.test(window.location.pathname)
```

You could attempt something using `window.location.href` like this:

```
/^https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/(login)?$/.test(window.location.href)
```

Problem is it's very fragile, it only needs something like a `hash` section to break it. It's much safer to let the browser parse the URL for you.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle your answer was really helpful. This is what I was looking for and thanks for suggesting me the right way.  Hence I am upvoting you.

Answer (score 0):

The need to check for preceding repetitions usually implies using lookbehind, here a negative one, which are not available in javascript.
The simpler way to go here is to code a bit:

```
var test = [ '/', '/login', '//', '/login/login' ];

var reForFail = /(\/(?:login)?)\1$/;
var reForMatch = /\/(?:login)?$/;

console.log(test.map(e => !reForFail.test(e) && reForMatch.test(e)));
```

You may also have a look at Steven Levithan's [mimic-lookbehind-javascript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript).